# Проблема в работе с потоками

Tags: c++, строки, файловый-ввод-вывод

Вопрос заключается в следующем, когда я делаю cout<<"Введите фамилию.." то прописываю cin.ignore, т.к. при вызове следующего cout в консоли выводит 2 эти строки вместе

Например:   Введите фамилию отправителя: Введите имя отправителя:

cin.ignore решил эту проблему, но когда я хочу работать с файлом и ввести в него текст, fout.ignore не срабатывает и получается что 2 строки опять выводятся вместе. Не понимаю как исправить.

```
Letter* A = new Letter;
    string so, no, sp, np;
    int io, ip;
    double m;
    ifstream fout;
    fout.open("file.txt", ios::in);
    cout << "Введите фамилию отправителя: ";
    cin.ignore(1, '\n');
    fout.ignore(1, '\n');
    getline(fout , so);
    (*(A)).surname_otpr = so;
    cout << "Введите имя отправителя: ";
    |
    |
    |
    |
    fout.close();
```

Comment: Не очень понятна суть проблемы. Если вам нужен перевод строки, то делайте `cout << "\n";` или `cout << endl;`. `но когда я хочу работать с файлом и ввести в него текст` Что и в кого вы собрались вводить? Файл открыт для чтения, не для записи.

Comment: Да, я заметил уже что для чтения, но суть не в этом была. Если я пишу ofstream то тогда getline выдает ошибку: отсутствует экземпляр перегружен я функции

Comment: Ну так правильно. `getline` читает данные, а не выводит. Зачем вы пытаетесь считать данные из файла с помощью `getline`, если открыли его для записи, а не чтения?

Comment: Понял, а как тогда мне записать строку в файл, через fout(в моем случае)<< "строка"?

Comment: `fout << "строка 1"; fout << " продолжение строки 1\n"; fout << "c новой строки" << endl; fout << "опять с новой строки"; fout << " ... продолжаем\nа теперь новая";`?

Comment: Ну да, как то так